# The Largest Gap

Tags: statistics, algorithms, descriptive-statistics

If I have an X amount of randomly generated positive numbers, what type of algorithm could I run to find the following:

- Precisely where the largest difference exists between two of the numbers?
- How much is that difference?
- Where does the smallest gap exist?
- How much is that difference?
- Generate a list of all differences and how many occurrences there are of each difference

It has been a while since I have taken any sort of math class, so pardon the potentially inaccurate tags.

Ideally I'm looking for a way to generate a list of all the differences, and then place those differences into a descending order. Once the list of all the differences into a descending order is created, we still need to be able to identify where in the original set of numbers, each particular difference takes place.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to run an equation.  If you were to sort the $X$ randomly generated numbers, which takes $O(X \ln X)$ steps, then the smallest and largest gaps can be found by making another single pass through the sorted values.

Comment: By "largest difference" do you mean the largest gap, a difference of two "consecutively ordered" values in your sample?

Comment: Yes the largest gap of two consecutively ordered values in the sample

Comment: Ideally looking for a way to generate a list of all the differences and then the idea is to place those differences into a descending order. Once the list of all the differences into a descending order is created, you will still need to be able to identify where in the original set of numbers, each particular difference takes place.

Comment: As I said earlier please pardon my mathematical vernacular

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of all differences, then two sortings are called for:  the first sort orders the random sample of size $X$, and the second sort orders the resulting $X-1$ differences of consecutive values (thereby grouping equal "gaps" together to facilitate counting their frequencies).

Let $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_X$ be the original sample of positive integers, possibly with repetitions.  After sorting these, which can be done with $O(X \ln X)$ complexity, we have a relabelled/ordered sample:

$$ m_1 \le m_2 \le \ldots \le m_X $$

Now we can take the consecutive differences, giving us $X-1$ gaps also with possible repetitions, $g_i = m_{i+1} - m_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,X-1$.

The second sort, sorting these $g_i$, gives you all the information about the largest, the smallest, and most frequent (mode) gap.

---

To be able to trace a particular gap back to the original items which produce that difference requires keeping some bookkeeping information with the arrays as we sort them.  This is largely a programming implementation issue, but we can sketch the idea.

Suppose the original sample of five positive integers $k_i$ were numbered as "key-value" pairs `(i,k)`:

```
(1,6) (2,5) (3,2) (4,11) (5,7) <---- k (unsorted)
```

Then sorting on the second "value" coordinate rearranges these into:

```
(3,2) (2,5) (1,6) (5,7) (4,11) <---- m (sorted)
```

We will then be able to recover the original *location* of such values from their first "key" coordinate (an index into the original sample sequence).

To continue the example, we construct the corresponding four gaps $g_i$ using the rearranged/sorted locations:

```
(1,3) (2,1) (3,1) (4,4) <---- g unsorted
```

The second sort uses the "gap" values and carries the new location-of-gap information along with it:

```
(2,1) (3,1) (1,3) (4,4) <---- g sorted
```

From this we see the smallest gap is 1, that this occurs twice, and that the largest gap is 4 (occurring only once).

If we want to know where that largest gap came from, we use the first coordinate of `(4,4)` to determine that it was the difference between the fourth and fifth sorted samples, $g_4 = m_5 - m_4$.  Then we use the earlier array of pairs representing $m_i$ to find that $m_5$ was originally $k_4$ and $m_4$ was $k_5$.

Thus by adding these "keys" to the key-value pairs, we are able to tell which locations of the original sample produced the largest gap (or any other gap, as listed in the final differences).

Comment: Had the chance to go over this briefly. Looks great from what I can see but haven't had the chance to sit down and work this out myself. I appreciate your help so far and will get back to you soon.